# Why does Proto-Balto-Slavic have form *aśís?

Tags: proto-indo-european

Why does Proto-Balto-Slavic have form *a**ś**ís (with one s in the stem)? despite of the fact that Old Prussian has word a**ss**is (compare PIE *h₂eḱs-i-s)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most probable reason for the double `<S>` in the Old Prussian word *a**ss**is* (“axis”) is that it was recorded by a German who used the German orthography. In German, a single `<S>` between two vowel letters is invariably pronounced as [z], a voiced sibilant:

> *Germ.* Hase [ˈhaːzə] — *Eng.* “hare”
> *Germ.* lesen [ˈleːzən] — *Eng.* “read”
> *Germ.* Basis [ˈbaːzis] — *Eng.* “basis, base”
> *Germ.* Kasus [ˈkaːzʊs] — *Eng.* “case (*linguistics*)”

To write the voiceless [s] between two vowels, the most common way out is to double the `<S>`:

*Germ.* Wasser [ˈvasɐ] — *Eng.* “water”
*Germ.* müssen [ˈmʏsən] — *Eng.* “must”

In foreign names the double `<S>` for the intervocalic [s] is used often. For example, the name of Vasilisa the Beautiful (Василиса [vɐsʲɪˈlʲisə]), a recurring character of Russian fairy tales, is spelled as “[Die schöne Wassilissa](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Die_sch%C3%B6ne_Wassilissa)”  in German.

Since in all the rest of the Balto-Slavic languages the consonant in the stem of the word for “axis” is single (Baltic: *Lith.* ašis, *Latv* ass (“-s” being the Nominative Singular suffix, Gen. sg. *asi* ), Slavic: os, osa, oś [ɔɕ], ось [osʲ], вісь [visʲ]), it is most probable that it was single in Old Prussian, too. It was just *spelled* as a double `<S>` to assure its reading as the voiceless sibilant [s]. Don't forget that German (and English too) has no long/gemminated consonant sounds, the double consonant letters *do not* mean the consonant sounds they stand for are in any way long. In German orthography, double `<S>` is always pronounced as [s], never as [sː].

The reason why the PIE **ḱs* gave the PBS **ś* is explained like this ([Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proto-Balto-Slavic_language#Ruki_law)):

> It appears that palatovelars yielded fricatives in Proto-Balto-Slavic before the effect of RUKI law, so that **ḱs* appears simply as **ś*. Compare:
>
> - Slavic **desnъ* "right (i.e. opposite to left)" (OCS *desnъ*, Russian *désnyj*, Serbo-Croatian *dèsnī*), Lithuanian *dẽšinas* < Proto-Balto-Slavic **deśinas* < PIE **déḱsinos* (Latin *dexter*, Sanskrit *dákṣiṇa*)
> - Slavic **osь* "axle, axis" (OCS *osь*, Russ. *os’*, SCr. *ȏs*), Lithuanian *ašis* < Proto-Balto-Slavic **aśís* < PIE **h₂éḱsis* (Latin *axis*, Sanskrit *ákṣas*).